# Creating a list of stacks in python

Tags: python, list, object, stack, queue

so I am trying to create a list of stack objects in Python. I have first created a class Stack that has simple methods that a Stack should have. I have then created another class called Stacks. I am trying to create a list of stacks. If a stack has more than 3 elements, it creates a new stack but I get an error when I try to display the elements. Could someone point out what I might be doing wrong here please?

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items =  []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def printStack(self):
        for item in reversed(self.items):
            print (item)


class Stacks:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stacks = []
        self.noOfStacks = 0
        self.itemsOnStack = 0

    def dev(self):
        self.stacks.append(Stack())
        # if len(self.stacks) != 0:
        #     self.noOfStacks += 1

    def push(self, item):
        if self.itemsOnStack > 3:
            self.dev()
        else:
            self.itemsOnStack += 1
            self.stacks[self.noOfStacks].push(item)

    def pop(self, stackNo):
        return self.stacks(noOfStacks).pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.stacks)

    def printtack(self, index):
        print (len(self.stacks(index)))
        self.stacks(index).printStack()


stacky = Stacks()
stacky.dev()
stacky.push(3)
stacky.printtack(0)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Make sure you post Python code with correct indentation. Otherwise you are introducing new problems into the code.

Comment: FWIW, `collections.deque` can be used as a stack, and it's generally a little faster than using a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note as [kshikama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2750819/kshikama) said indexing should be done using `[]` not `()`,the other problem is using the `len()` method in the stack class u most override the `__len__()` method or as u have given use the size() method

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items =  []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def printStack(self):
        for item in reversed(self.items):
            print (item)

class Stacks:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stacks = []
        self.noOfStacks = 0
        self.itemsOnStack = 0

    def dev(self):
        self.stacks.append(Stack())
        #if len(self.stacks) != 0:
            #self.noOfStacks += 1

    def push(self, item):

        if self.itemsOnStack > 3:
            self.dev()
        else:
            self.itemsOnStack += 1
            self.stacks[self.noOfStacks].push(item)


    def pop(self, stackNo):
        return self.stacks(noOfStacks).pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.stacks)

    def printtack(self, index):
        print (self.stacks[index].size())
        self.stacks[index].printStack()
stacky = Stacks()
stacky.dev()
stacky.push(3)
stacky.printtack(0)
```

OUTPUT

```
1
3
```

Comment: Omg im such an idiot for using () as index instead of []. Thanks everyone above for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing lists in Python works by [] not (). Try

```
 def printtack(self, index):
    self.stacks[index].printStack()
```